# Sprint planning - Is it best practice to keep a backlog item scoped to a single sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

When planning a new sprint:
Just wondering if it is generally best practice to have a backlog item no more complex than those things that can fit on a single sprint?  In other words, the tasks involved, if its likely that all the tasks can't get done in the upcoming sprint, then you should consider breaking up the backlog item into separate items?

Comment: There is a general backlog and a sprint backlog, to which one do you mean?

Comment: Yes. User stories should be sized so they can fit in a single sprint. If it's bigger than a sprint, your backlog item is too big and it should be decomposed into multiple, smaller stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes.

With more detail explanation:

In Sprint Planning, the team chooses the backlog items they will work on in the upcoming sprint. The team **chooses backlog items based on priority and what they believe they can complete in the sprint.** The Sprint Backlog is the list of items the team plans to deliver in the sprint. Often, each item on the Sprint Backlog is broken down into tasks. Once all members agree the Sprint Backlog is achievable, the Sprint starts.

> To identify the backlog items that the team feels it can commit to
>   completing in the sprint, it's usually based on experience with
>   previous sprints.
>
> Your project comes with several predefined sprints. You can quickly
>   add more sprints from your backlog as needed. Or, change the dates of
>   the predefined sprints.

More details please have a look at official tutorial here: [Assign backlog items to a sprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

In general your stories should be small enough to fit in a single sprint and large enough to provide business value.  If they are bigger than that they either need to be refactored into separate stories or be converted into an epic with smaller stories.